# Nutch giving an Shuffle error while indexing to SOLR.

Tags: solr, nutch

The Nutch Crawler succesfully indexed the documents upto a particular time. At some point its stopeed abruptly don't know the reasons. i am posting the logs may i know the reason for this.

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.InMemoryMapOutput.<init>(InMemoryMapOutput.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.unconditionalReserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.reserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.copyMapOutput(LocalFetcher.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.doCopy(LocalFetcher.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.run(LocalFetcher.java:85)
2018-08-30 03:15:54,758 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:873)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:147)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:239)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

It's a memory error
try adjust in solr.in.sh

```
SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms512m -Xmx5120m"
```

For me after this it's work